# How to improve this CSS question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

This question I asked ([CSS properties for Table with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371934/css-properties-for-table-with-angular)) has not been well received.

Downvotes indicate some users find the question either not clear, does not show adequate research effort, or do not find it useful.

I would like some help to improve this question so it gets a better reception.

Comment: "It doesn't have any effect" -- should you not have indicated what effect you hoped to get? Or (pardoning my lack of CSS) do you consider this 'blatantly obvious'?

Comment: Research effort is likely the culprit here; CSS does not allow nesting as you have it in your question. Some investigation into [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) would clear that up.

Comment: If you are using a preprocessor you should edit your question to state this otherwise we will simply consider that you are wrongly using CSS as stated by @HereticMonkey

Comment: ^ even if you were using a preprocessor your code is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3obmspud/ so your question will fall into *cannot reproduce* and will also be closed

Comment: @Heretic Thank you. I will read about css selectors.